# Calling a static method from Thymeleaf TEXT template - how to bypass the Restricted mode

Tags: thymeleaf

Is it possible to call a static method from a Thymeleaf textual template?

[Official guide](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) mentions that it should be possible to call a method like this:

```
<p th:text="${@myapp.translator.Translator@translateToFrench(textVar)}">Some text here...</p>
```

When I try to use it in my textual template (TemplateResolver's mode is set to TemplateMode.TEXT), I get a this exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "@java.lang.System@currentTimeMillis()" (template: "template.txt" - line 1, col 18)
```

Here is my sample template:

```
System millis: [(${@java.lang.System@currentTimeMillis()})]
```

After googling for a while, I also found this form of calling methods:

```
System millis: [(${T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()})]
```

which fails with the same error.

What I need to do is somehow allow usage of a custom number formatter class from a template (functionality of the `#numbers` utility object is not rich enough for my case).
I can call methods on a non-static class by providing it as a context variable like this:

```
Some value: [(${formatter.format(someValue)})]
```

but it would be easier for me to use a static class without a need to explicitly adding it to each template's context.

BTW, I do not use Spring, just pure Thymeleaf.

### Update

I should've spend more time to analyze the stack trace of the Thymeleaf exception I got.
It turns out, that the root cause of this behavior was the `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes is forbidden in this context` exception, which is results from this change: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/809

Downgrading to Thymeleaf 3.0.11 "fixes" it.

Now I'm looking for a solution to bypass this new Resctricted mode on the latest Thymeleaf (3.0.12 for the moment). I'm sure it's safe in my case, because I'm the only author of both code and templates.

Comment: Dunno how you have your Thymeleaf set up, but your first example syntax (`System millis: [(${@java.lang.System@currentTimeMillis()})]`) [works fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/hvRst8m.jpg).

Comment: Yes, it turns out, I wasn't careful enough to read the whole stack trace. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to use the `th:with` attribute.  It's a little more verbose, but still should allow you the same flexibility. (This works for me on `3.0.12.RELEASE`.)

```
[# th:with="time=${@java.lang.System@currentTimeMillis()}"]System millis: [[${time}]][/]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/816#issuecomment-826401631 has extensive info on why this was done and possible workarounds. In your case, it will be best to add a model attribute in your controller and use that instead of calling the static method in the template.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  public String myControllerMethod(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("time", System.currentTimeMillis());

    return "name-of-the-thymeleaf-template";
  }
}
```

and update your template to use:

```
System millis: [(${time})]
```

Comment: Thanks, but a call to `System.currentTimeMillis()` was there just as a sample. As I said in my question, I need to use a custom number formatter, and it's more convenient in my case to set the number format in templates and not in the model itself. Now I ended up adding an instance of my formatter to the Context object and calling its methods from templates, it works fine so far.